# Is there a built-in way to recursively print a tree?

Tags: go, struct, printing, interface

I am learning Go and looking for a way to print my AST (For reference, I'm following along with Ruslan's excellent [Let's Build a Simple Interpreter](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part1/)).

I am printing the root with the following:

```
tree := par.Parse()
fmt.Printf("\nParse Tree:\n%#v\n", tree)
```

Which prints:

```
Parse Tree:
&Node.Program{name:"PART10AST", block:(*Node.Block)(0x11b32160)}
```

Is there a way to recursively print a node, and all child nodes?  Something to the effect of:

```
&Node.Program{name:"PART10AST", block:(*Node.Block{decl: *Node.declarations{...}, comp: *Node.Compound{...}})}
```

Is this functionality built in to Go in any way?  `Node` is an interface for several different types of `struct`s which store data and/or more `Node`s.

Comment: you don't have any built-in way to print that data, but you can implement a `print` or `toString` method for your AST if you have access to the attributes of `Node`.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for ast.Fprint, https://godoc.org/go/ast#Fprint